# C++: dereference a hexadecimal value, kind of a syntax question

Tags: c++

How can I make the third cout work? I want to derence some **exact** memory address (I'm making a bold assumption that it would stay the same same every time I execute the program), in this case 0x6ffdf0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;



int main(){
    string colors = "blue";
    string* pointer = &colors;

    cout << pointer << endl;  //outputs 0x6ffdf0

    cout << *pointer << endl; //outputs "blue"

    cout << *0x6ffdf0;        //I want this to also output "blue"


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a *very* bold assumption indeed. I wouldn't do that, if I were you.

Comment: Setting aside that this is a bad idea, for starters you would need to cast it as a pointer to a string.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make it work safely, it is not a safe assumption. There are no guarantees about where the stack will be in your process, how much will be on the stack before the entry into main, etc, and in practice the amount on the stack is likely to be a function of the particular command line used to launch your program.

That said, for academic purposes, the syntax you're looking for to enact your unsafe assumption is:

```
std::cout << *reinterpret_cast<const std::string *>(0x6ffdf0);
```

As a rule of thumb, always get suspicious if you see a `reinterpret_cast`; it means 'treat this bit pattern as if it were this type, results be damned'.

Comment: You can use `reinterpret_cast<T&>` instead of `* reinterpret_cast<T *>`

Answer (score 0):

Each time you are running the program the address of the object colors can be different.

If you want to reinterpret an address as an integer value then you can write something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string colors = "blue";
    string* pointer = &colors;

    cout << pointer << endl;  // here can be any value 
                              // that can be changed from time to time

    cout << *pointer << endl; //outputs "blue"

    uintptr_t n = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>( pointer );

    cout << *reinterpret_cast<string *>( n );

    return 0;
}
```